# How can I get the Number of Results from a search using the API

Tags: feature-request, search, api

What I am after is the total results for a given search. In the site it is listed as "Results 425" and then the page shows the first page's results.

But in the API it seems to only return back a set of resutls and no meta information about the search in general.

Am I missing something

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `total` field which is not returned by default, you need to select it in the filter. See the description of the [Common Wrapper Object](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper).

[Example](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?fromdate=1298764800&todate=1298851200&order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow&filter=!--l6ygKpWzFx): there were 623 SO users created on 2011-02-27